# Using for loop to get for specific iteration result in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

I need help in somewhere in javascript

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
```

This ajax call result returns some data (around 31).

Here is an example:

`obj[0] = 10, obj[1]=20 ,obj[2]=30 , obj[4]=21,obj[5]=16,obj[6]=54`  here I want to get value of

`obj[0] and ob[4]` using for loop . And I also need to do this  for  `obj[10] and obj[14]` the difference will be `5` between the `i` values .

Any idea or help?

Comment: Why would you use a for loop if you know you want 0 and 4? just get 0 and 4. (or 8 according to your title....)

Comment: Ah, so you want every 5th. that makes a lot more sense. Though i still dont know where `8` in your title comes in.

Comment: I want to use same process for others . you know , the Difference will be 5 between I values

Comment: yes sorry I forgot to update it

Comment: You want obj[0] and then obj[4] .. then the difference is 4 and not 5. right?

Comment: it's 4, and then 6... very strange.

Comment: I guess you could iterate in steps of 10, getting both i and i+4 on each iteration

Comment: Why do you need 0, 4, 5, 9, 10, and 14? what made you select these indexes instead of, say, 2, 6, 11, and 15? we need to know how you are deciding what indexes you want to grab so that we can help you figure out how to iterate over it effectively.

Comment: ok.let say ajax call returns 24 obj obj[0]...ob[23] and each one has value and I want to get only obj[0] - obj[7] and obj[8]-obj[15] and obj[16] - obj[23]

Answer (score 1):

```
var iterator=0;
for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) { 
    if(i == iterator){
       alert(obj[iterator]);
       iterator= iterator + 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is actulally small issue I am having. since I want to get obj0 and obj4 also obj5 and obj9 , it makes problem when I try to get obj5 because its adding +4 each time

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this (a pseudo code)

```
int i = 0;

while(i < 31)
{
 print(i);
 i = i + 4; 
}
```

Comment: definitely should be +5, since he always wants 0 and 4. 0,4,10,14,20,24,30

Comment: @KevinB, home come? to me it looks like a skip of 4 index and not 5.

Comment: @KevinB, accepted. Unless OP clarifies it, it's indeed strange.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood, you want to skip 5 on each step:

```
var array = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split(''); // something that generates an array just to show an example

var i = 0;

for (; i < array.length;) {
    console.log(i, array[i]);
    i += 5;
}
```

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sx5k7/)